# How do I make gtest not completely shutdown when it hits an assert? (not a test assert)

Tags: c++, googletest

In the developer code, there are many places where it calls assert(xyz):

(from assert.h)

`#define assert(_Expression) (void)( (!!(_Expression)) || (_wassert(_CRT_WIDE(#_Expression), _CRT_WIDE(__FILE__), __LINE__), 0) )`

When I run my tests through gtest and one of these asserts fails, then my executable completely shuts down.

I want a way for gtest to just catch this assert, fail the test, and the continue execution. Is this possible?

Comment: Check for [death tests](https://code.google.com/p/googletest/wiki/AdvancedGuide#Death_Tests) please.

Answer (score 1):

As from [google test's reference documentation](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/docs/advanced.md#how-to-write-a-death-test)

> #### How to Write a Death Test
>
> Google Test has the following macros to support death tests:

[image]

> where statement is a statement that is expected to cause the process to die, predicate is a function or function object that evaluates an integer exit status, and regex is a regular expression that the stderr output of statement is expected to match. Note that statement can be any valid statement (including compound statement) and doesn't have to be an expression.

You can use these test macros to intercept native `exit()` or `_exit()` calls of your tested code, if these return different values from `0`.

---

As for your comment

> *"What if the test itself doesn't expect it, but it happens anyway? I don't want the rest of my execution to stop. Just that test to fail, then continue on."*

Sorry, you can't prevent that. That's what `assert()` statements are designed for, and act as a self assertion for certain functions that test the inputs or conditions they achieve.
You may try to compile your testing and under test code using the `-DNDEBUG` compiler option, but this will leavee you with even more obscure issues hitting undefined behavior or such.

If a test case is likely to hit an unexpected assertion, there's either something wrong with your test cases input values, or with the code tested.
So you should setup reproducible conditions, that either the test case fails with the assert (and the unit tester runnable carries on), or the whole thing blows up (exits the test runner process), which means your tested input didn't pass (and you'll need to change the testcase, or fix the the code under test).

Comment: This is a case where the test is expecting an exit. What if the test itself doesn't expect it, but it happens anyway? I don't want the rest of my execution to stop. Just that test to fail, then continue on.

Comment: If there is an immediate possibility of a test failing in such a way that the program is halted you should always run it as a death test.

Answer (score -3):

Basically, if the code you are testing is broken, the test cannot continue.

To keep gtest from crashing, make sure the code you are testing at least compiles properly, and input it is gathering is valid.

I am saying this not to be mean, but rather out of personal experience.  I use gtest and gmock for my own projects.  I have been playing around with code lately that was a bit out of my league (after all, the only way to grow is to stretch beyond your perceived limits).

The code was taking data from a data file, and this was crashing my tests, not because there was anything wrong with the test, but because I wasn't doing proper error checking yet for the functions that were reading from the file, and it was throwing a wrench in things when the program was getting a string, and wanted an integer.

Believe it or not, exceptions are a GOOD thing in tests.  You don't want to just ignore them and move on, you want to figure out what is causing them and make it stop.  That is the entire reason for testing.

Comment: I don't think OP is talking about ignoring an exception and carrying on, but rather the error will be flagged and other tests will still be ran.